# How to solve NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, angular-material

i'm a junior dev in angular and recently i have some issue about NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked.
the error was caused due to the spinner component

```
<div [hidden]="!visible" class="preloader">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
    <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the error occured when i press on the button

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-2"><button mat-mini-fab color="accent" (click)="onAddTheme(campagne)">
   <mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button></div>
</div>
```

```
onAddTheme(campagne: Campagne) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ThemeComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      data: campagne,
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.themesService.getThemeById(result).subscribe((theme: Theme) => {
          this.themes.push(theme);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

this is the template for teme.component.html

```
<form class="form-inline" [formGroup]="themeData">
  <div mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>None</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="libelle">
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let topic of themes" [value]="topic.id">{{ topic.libelle }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="onAddTheme()">Submit</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" type="button" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
visible: boolean = true;
spinnerStateChanged: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {
    this.spinnerStateChanged = this.spinner.spinnerState
      .subscribe((state: SpinnerState) => {
        this.visible = state.show;
        console.log(this.visible);
      });
  }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      this.visible = false;
    });
    /*this.visible = false;
    this.cd.detectChanges();*/
  }
```

Comment: this is the error i got:                                                                                                              Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'hidden': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

Comment: How is `visible` changed? Because it's your problem here

Comment: Could you provide a code where ```visible``` gets changed?

Comment: `visible: boolean = true;`
`spinnerStateChanged: Subscription;`

Comment: Thanks for the replied!! I added my spinner.component.ts up there